# Using previous command parameter in shell script

Tags: shell-script, cron, rsync

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avh -r /Parent/Folder1 /Destination/

if [ $? == 0 ]
then
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Success /Result/Success$(basename !:3)
else
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Failure  /Result/Failure$(basename !:3)
fi
```

***Question 1***

I am using rsync command to sync two folders in cent os.
If rsync command is successful then I copy a folder to Result directory from Success directory and append current date.This works fine

**What I want is that when I copy from success instead of appending date,
*Folder1* from the above command should be appended.So how?**

**Question 2**

I have automated this shell script in crontab.I want to pass Folder1 as parameter to the command in the automated script.So how??

## **Update:**

```
 if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
       cp /FolderCopyStatus/Success /Result/Success$(basename !:3)
    else
       cp /FolderCopyStatus/Failure  /Result/Failure$(basename !:3)
    fi
```

**Problem**: $(basename !:3) doesnot works in script but works in normal command like echo $(basename !:3)

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

`/usr/bin/rsync -avh -r /Parent/Folder1 /Destination/
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Success /Result/Success$(basename !^)
else
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Failure  /Result/Failure$(date +%F_%R)
fi`

**Question 2**

Make the first line of your script like this

`/usr/bin/rsync -avh -r /Parent/$1 /Destination/`

And then when you call the script call it like this

`/path/to/script Folder1`

Comment: (basename !:3) instead (of basename !^).Thanks

Comment: And I want pass parameter for rsync command in crontab